# Pascal Graph unit - detecting window close

Tags: freepascal

I wrote a Wireworld/Cellular Automata implementation using Lazarus/Free Pascal's Graph unit. My problem is that the user can simply click the close button on the graph window's top and it will close - but leave the application running in the background. What I am looking for is a method to check for the closing of an active graph window and issue an exit command if it's closed.

Comment: Looking up Graph unit reference, mostly. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to count on the window being closed. Leaving the normal console visible and closing THAT however closes the application normally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Use wingraph, it has better windows integration.

Have a look at how the FPC demoes (FPCTris and Samegame) handle it.